# I need to pass an variable into a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Thread thread1;
thread1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1700);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       System.out.println("testing");
    }
};
Thread thread2;
thread2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // ... your code here
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("testing");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
};
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
System.out.println("testing");
```

This is a striped down version of my program and highlights the problem i need to pass in the time it sleeps for but after looking around i can't seem to get it passed in i can only find info about passing to runnable.

Comment: *" i can only find info about passing to runnable."* Why do you think there were a difference?

Comment: A `Thread` can be treated much the same as a `Runnable`.  However if you want to literally use a `Runnable`, just follow the examples you have then make your thread like this: `thread1 = new Thread(myRunnable)`.  This is actually better than subclassing thread (like you have) because it's more flexible and also because it uses aggregation instead of inheritance (which is the preferred way to do it).

Comment: I am unable to understand it/make it work. I managed to edit and example and could pass it into runnable but not use it under run, meaning i couldn't use it in the main part of my thread like i want to above.

Comment: Thanks very much Markspace i will have a go now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below class, do you have any issue with it

```
public class TestThread {

    volatile static int time = 1700;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread1 Sleeped for : " + time + " millis");
            }
        };
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread2 Sleeped for : " + time + " millis");
            }
        };
        thread2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway this could be modified to support an unknown number of threads and different times for each of them

Comment: As you can see, time is not final variable. So can modify it , as many times, as you want to. Also you may use this variable in any no of threads

Comment: But may be modified value may not be visible to each thread immediately (due to thread cache). So you may need to make this variable as volatile

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a thread factory that takes sleep time and your custom code to execute:

```
interface CodeExecutor {
    void execute();
}

static class ThreadFactory {
    public static Thread newThread(int sleepTime, CodeExecutor customCode) {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    customCode.execute();
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    System.out.println("testing");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = ThreadFactory.newThread(100, new CodeExecutor() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            // here goes your custom code
        }
    });

    thread1.start();
    // create other threads
}
```